# C# Count Threading Not Working

Tags: c#, multithreading

Good afternoon everybody.
I am new to Parallel.ForEach and even newer to threading and I wanted to ask your opinion on what is wrong with this code.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;

namespace MultiThreading_Example
{

    class theMeter {

        int count1 = 0;

        public void CounterMeter()
        {
            while (this.count1 < 10000)
            {
                this.count1++;
                Console.WriteLine(this.count1);
            }
        }

    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            theMeter met = new theMeter();

            ThreadStart countForMe = new ThreadStart(met.CounterMeter);

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Thread t1 = new Thread(countForMe);
                t1.Start();
                t1.Join();
                t1.Abort();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what is wrong with this? I mean, I have tried doing it without t1.Join() and also have tried doing it on one thread. All are at the same speed. How can I get he program to process faster?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `t1.Join()` will wait while thread is ended, so it won't process it in parallel. If you want parallel execution, your Join and Abort(not sure that it's needed here at all) calls should be outside of `for`, and you would need to store each thread variable separately or in the some list.

Comment: In addition, note that you are primarily testing the speed of the console I/O. You can throw as many threads as you want at the problem, they won't be able to push characters through the console any faster than a single thread could. The question itself is too vague to really know what you're asking though. The `Join()` is definitely a problem as well, but the code doesn't show any mechanism for timing, so it's not even clear what you mean by "wrong with this" or "same speed".

Comment: The code doesn't show any mechanism of timing because I removed the stopwatch but now I understand what you mean. @Sergey could you post an example so I understand how the variables should be held separately? Like an array?

Comment: Why the title is related to [Parallel.Foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but in the question you are talking about normal thread?
Second: after the first thread is finished will be printed nothing since while statement will be false everytime

Comment: The title is not misleading and the code works but not at the desired speed. Read OP and then try replying again.

Comment: It does not matter if they are synchronized or not, I just need that done. As Sergey mentioned you need to hold the variables in an array or so but what after. ForEach array item do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample of working example. The difference is that each thread is stored in list and started in parallel, and then in the end we wait for each thread.

```
class theMeter
{
    private int count1 = 0;

    public void CounterMeter()
    {
        while (this.count1 < 10000)
        {
            this.count1++;
            Console.WriteLine(this.count1);
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        theMeter met = new theMeter();
        ThreadStart countForMe = new ThreadStart(met.CounterMeter);

        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(countForMe);
            t1.Start();
            threads.Add(t1);
        }

        // here we will wait for completion of every thread that was created and added to list
        threads.ForEach(t => t.Join());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This code has a couple of issues worth to mention:

1. Each thread uses the same `theMeter` instance, so each of them will iterate the same `this.count1` variable, so ***it's not so thread safe***. IMO, the better approach is to create own instance for each thread and divide work for each of them. So they won't share the same resources and it won't cause shared resource access issues.
2. If any of threads will stuck, then your program will freeze. As `Join` will wait unlimited amount of time for that. If your thread might take a lot of time(network, db, etc), then you can use `Join` with timeout and then call `Abort`. But still using of `Abort` method isn't recommended, as thread should complete his logic in graceful way, not by cruel interruption of `Abort` method.
3. In your orignal example you have 1000 threads, and it's too much, as they will fight for CPU resources and might make things much slower. But it will depend on actual things they will do and where bottleneck will be. If this is CPU intensive task, then thread count should be similar to CPUs count. If this they are doing network requests, then it might depend on network bandiwth.
4. Another way might be using real `Parallel.ForEach` or `Task` classes, that can make things a bit easier.

Sample with actual `Parallel.ForEach` will be like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        theMeter met = new theMeter();

        Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).AsParallel().ForAll((i) => met.CounterMeter());
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

But you won't have so much flexibility here, but it's easier

Comment: This is example how *not to write* code that modify single shared variable. Not sure why you decided to copy invalid code provided by OP for  that.

Comment: agree, so thats why i've described what issues has original code

Comment: Thank you for that. I understand how the code works and the issues with it now. So in the end, I might as well divide that 1000 by number of threads and make each do it's job.